# Can I fix my broken Nikkor 24-85 D?

Tags: lens, nikon, equipment-damage

I slipped with my camera the other day while at a wedding shoot. 
I fell on the lens and this happened:

[image: picture of the damage]

The lens is now stuck at 24 to 35.
Has anyone here experienced this? 
Is there any DIY fix?

I am in tears right now.

Comment: Yeah, this lens is beyond repair. My condolences. If you havent already done so, I suggest you invest in a grip strap or neck strap to help avoid tragedies like this in future.

Answer (score 5):

There is of course no DIY "quick fix" for a lens that has been smashed. This is a good reason why insurance on your gear is a great idea.  You could contact Nikon and see if they will take this in for repair, but as this is not all that pricey of a lens (by lens standards) it might cost you half of the cost of the unit to repair if they can repair it. I would recommend looking at a new unit at this point.

Comment: You will probably want to send in the camera for inspection as well. That can't have been good for the lens mount (or camera frame), and if it's bent or damaged a repaired lens will most likely not function or focus correctly.